# Automapper configuration for grouping the data

Tags: c#, api, automapper

I am having the following models

Source:

```
public class Opportunity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid QuotationId { get; set; }
    public int? QuotationNumber { get; set; }
    public int? QuotationVersionNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Target:

```
public class OpportunityDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<QuotationDto> Quotations { get; set; }
}

public class QuotationDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int VersionNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The data I would fetch from my database would be flat as the Opportunity model and my api is exposing the OpportunityDto model. 
so, in my auto-mapper configuration, I have the following code:

```
services
    .AddSingleton(new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<OpportunityDto, Opportunity>().ReverseMap();
        cfg.CreateMap<QuotationDto, Quotation>().ReverseMap();
    }).CreateMapper())
```

what I want to achive is a list of unique opportunities and each opportunity would have a nested member which would have the list of the quotations.
how can I make the automapper perform this grouping? right now the Quotations member of the opportunityDto returned from the api is always empty.

Comment: I would personally manually do a `GroupBy`  LINQ call, following by mapping the first object of each list to `OpportunityDto`, and then each group list to `QuotationDto`. Sorry about to leave so don't have time to provide full solution

Comment: Thanks @MichalCiechan for your response. I think I would do the same but would have been amazing if automapper could already support this custom mapping as well.

Comment: You could potentially add a custom mapping from `IEnumerable<Opportunity>` to `OpportunityDto` with the custom mapping, therefore then can re-use the logic.

Comment: @MichalCiechan my attempt for make it work with IEnumerable<Opportunity> to OpportunityDto mapping failed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## AutoMapper Configuration

You can do something like the following:

```
    public static void InitialiseMapper()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable<Opportunity>, OpportunityDto>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Id, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.FirstOrDefault().Id))
                .ForMember(x => x.Name, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.FirstOrDefault().Name))
                .ForMember(x => x.Quotations,
                    x => x.MapFrom(y => Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Opportunity>, IEnumerable<QuotationDto>>(y).ToArray()))
                ;

            cfg.CreateMap<Opportunity, QuotationDto>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Id, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.QuotationId))
                .ForMember(x => x.Number, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.QuotationNumber))
                .ForMember(x => x.VersionNumber, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.QuotationVersionNumber))
                ;
        });
    }
```

## Test

Which then successfully knows how to map as demonstrated by the following test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var oppo1Guid = Guid.NewGuid();

        var opportunities = new List<Opportunity>
        {
            new Opportunity
            {
                Id = oppo1Guid,
                Name = "Mikeys Oppurtunity",
                QuotationId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                QuotationNumber = 169,
                QuotationVersionNumber = 80,
            },

            new Opportunity
            {
                Id = oppo1Guid,
                Name = "Mikeys Oppurtunity",
                QuotationId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                QuotationNumber = 170,
                QuotationVersionNumber = 20,
            }
        };

        var dtos = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Opportunity>, OpportunityDto>(opportunities);

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtos, Formatting.Indented);

        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
```

And the output is

## Test Output

```
{
  "Id": "623c17df-f748-47a2-bc7e-35eb124dbfa3",
  "Name": "Mikeys Oppurtunity",
  "Quotations": [
    {
      "Id": "ad8b31c2-6157-4b7f-a1f2-9f8cfc1474b7",
      "Number": 169,
      "VersionNumber": 80
    },
    {
      "Id": "515aa560-6a5b-47da-a214-255d1815e153",
      "Number": 170,
      "VersionNumber": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Afflatus I would give you the idea that you can follow. I am assuming that you are using AspNetCore based on your services variable.

You can create an extension method like this, to later make a call on your ConfigurationServices like `services.RegisterMappingsWithAutomapper()`:

```
public static IServiceCollection RegisterMappingsWithAutomapper(this IServiceCollection services)
{
   var mapperConfig = AutoMapperHelper.InitializeAutoMapper();
   services.AddScoped<IMapper>(provider => new Mapper(mapperConfig));
   return services;
}
```

The InitializeAutoMapper is below:

```
public static class AutoMapperHelper
{
    public static MapperConfiguration InitializeAutoMapper()
    {
        //Load here all your assemblies
        var allClasses = AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies();

        MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            if (allClasses != null)
            { 
                //here normally I add another Profiles that I use with reflection, marking my DTOs with an interface
                cfg.AddProfile(new MappingModelsAndDtos(allClasses));
                cfg.AddProfile(new MyCustomProfile());
            }
        });

        return config;
    }
}
```

now you need to implement the Profile, in this case MyCustomProfile

```
public class ModelProfile : Profile
{
    public ModelProfile()
    {
        //put your source and destination here
        CreateMap<MySource, MyDestination>()
                .ConvertUsing<MySourceToMyDestination<MySource, MyDestination>>();
    }
}
```

you need to implement MySourceToMyDestination class then.
Bellow is an example of the code of how I am using it in my projects

```
public class ApplicationModel2ApplicationDto : ITypeConverter<ApplicationModel, ApplicationDto>
{
    public ApplicationDto Convert(ApplicationModel source, ApplicationDto destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var mapper = context.Mapper;
        try
        {
            destination = new ApplicationDto
            { 
                ApplicationId = source.ApplicationId,
                ApplicationName = source.ApplicationName,
                Documents = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DocumentDto>>(source.Documents),
                Tags = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TagInfoDto>>(source.TagInfos)
            };
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }

        return destination;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps