# Map one-to-many relationship with Automapper in c#

Tags: c#, automapper

If I have a fetch from the database that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
JOIN Pet ON Person.Id = Pet.PersonId
```

Lets say that this gives a collection of `PersonWithPetsDataModel` with duplicated persons:

```
public class PersonWithPetsDataModel
{
    public Guid PersonId {get;set;}
    public string PersonName {get;set;}
    public Guid PetId {get;set;}
    public string PetName {get;set;}
}
```

and I want to map this into

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid PersonId {get;set;}
    public string PersonName {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Pet> Pets {get;set;}
}

public class Pet
{
    public Guid PetId {get;set;}
    public string PetName {get;set;}
}
```

How can I do this with automapper? Thanks!

Comment: I don't follow. How does this relate to AutoMapper?

Comment: Can you reformulate the question? AutoMapper maps from a class to a class, not from a DB table. Using ORM (like Entity Framework) you can map data form tables to DTO classes (Data Transfer Objects). Then AutoMapper can map them on other entities.

Comment: Actually AM, with EFs help, _does_ map directly from the DB. `ProjectTo ` does exactly that.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've updated the question.

Comment: @John Maybe you guys are discussing something outside of the question (which is fine). Just want to make clear that the question doesn't have anything to do with EF.

Comment: @FatAlbert We were, apologies. I've removed my comments so there's less of a mess here. I expect you'll need to do some grouping before you can map. Your question seems similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503133/automapper-configuration-for-grouping-the-data).

Comment: @FatAlbert In fact EF and `ProjectTo` work together and this is how an optimal solution looks. And the grouping should be done with EF, before the projection.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu but I don't use EF. Wonder if and how the grouping could be done with automapper?

Comment: For anyhing other than trivial apps, grouping is best done in the DB, not in memory :) AM doesn't do grouping, LINQ does. But if you don't use EF, you should write the grouping in SQL.

Comment: If your models don't have private setters and have parameterless constructers, you can use Dapper to directly map your data into them. Fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments above got me in the right direction and I think I figured it out:

```
CreateMap<IEnumerable<PersonWithPetsDataModel>, Person>()
    .ForMember(x => x.PersonId, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.FirstOrDefault().PersonId))
    .ForMember(x => x.PersonName, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.FirstOrDefault().PersonName))
    .ForMember(x => x.Pets, opt => 
    opt.MapFrom(x => x.Select(y => new Pet
    {
        PetId = y.PetId
        PetName = y.PetName
    })));
```

Thanks for your engagement. Maybe this answer will help someone else in the future.

Comment: For 10 source objects, this is fine, for 1000 it's terrible.